# IBM FileNet P8 Local Deployment

Tags: filenet-p8, filenet-content-engine

I needed to deploy IBM Filenet P8 Content engine in my local system. How can I get the ear file to deploy it locally? I searched in the net, but I didn't get any link for downloading.

Answer (score 1):

Installing `Content Engine` is much more than deploying corresponding EAR. While you can obtain that EAR via [IBM Fix Central](https://www-945.ibm.com/support/fixcentral/) as part of any fix pack for `Content Engine`, this won't get you anywhere. A lot of configuration is required during the installation.

Answer (score 0):

You would need IBM passport advantage access to get the binaries for installation. I don't think there's a way to get to other than this.